# Wattage of adapter to size my inverter

Tags: power-supply, power, inverter

I have a couple of appliances that already have their power specified on them. However A few of them do not. The device is powered from an external power brick adapter.

One adapter for instance has the following specifications on it:

Input: 100-240V ~ 1.5A (I use 230Vac)

Output: 12V – 3.33A

My question is therefore which power value calculation do I use, the input (264.5W) of output (39.96W)? In order to know how to size my inverter.

I am sure this may be a duplicate question but I cannot search through every post to find that answer and the search field is not narrowing down the options alot.

Comment: The adapter in this case is a "consumer", so the the specs that need to be accounted for are its input. OTOH 1.5A at 240V seems to much for much lower output power.

Comment: Typically the 40W output power + some margin because the adapter is not 100% efficient. The input current rating is a maximum surge current of short duration.

Comment: The input current rating is cautious for a reason : it allows for surge currents, e.g. when starting. Rate the inverter to match this for reliable operation. Or you may find the inverter shuts down every time you connect the adapter.

Comment: power supplies of this size are expected to be >85% efficient but have a surge power on startup that depends on the phase of the Vac when switching on but mainly due to charging up storage caps may take up to 10x the power briefly.  So consider an input load  proportional <50W at rated load and a 500% surge on start. With 10% idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter's current will be largest at 100 V, not 240 V, the 1.5 A doesn't apply at all voltages.

Then for a low power device like this, the power factor is probably quite poor, maybe as low as 0.7, I guess. This means the current will be 1.4 x what you'd expect from the power. The inverter still has to supply this current.

Then the efficiency of the adapter is probably only 80%.

This still leaves a factor of two which can't be explained.

At 240 V, you can probably consider the steady state fully loaded current to be under 0.5 A, or 100 VA.
The inrush current when it is first connected, could be a lot higher, but inverters usually handle this with a brief voltage drop.

By the way, small inverters are notoriously overstated in their power ability. I have a cheap 120 watt inverter which can't power a laptop. You can see it in the price range, you can pay $25 or $250 for a 200 watt inverter, depending on how serious your application is.

Comment: okay so I need to use AC to calculate the size of the inverter + margin?

Comment: Yes AC but not the whole 1.5 A, that is at 100 V and seems to include a healthy margin. Best would be to measure it with a multimeter, total current x 240 is the inverter VA required. Plus a margin for inverter marketing bs.

Answer (score 0):

- power supplies of this size are expected to be >85% efficient but have a surge power on startup that depends on the phase of the Vac when switching on but mainly due to charging up storage caps may take up to 10x the power briefly.

So consider an input load  proportional <50W at rated load and a 500%  surge on start. With 10% idle

Comment: So a 300W inverter should be okay?